# Pending processes in MySQL after calling EntityManager.find()

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, hikaricp

I wrote a DAL which abstracts the access to the data of a MySQL DB and I'm facing an annoying problem with the processes running in MySQL.

I have an `User` `Entity` (targeting a `User` DB table) and this `UserDAO`

```
public class UserDAO {

    @PersistenceContext private EntityManager entityManager;

    public User create(User user)
    {
        ...
    }

    public void delete(String username)
    {
        ...
    }

    public User findByUsername(String username)
    {
        User user = entityManager.find(User, username);

        return user;
    }

    public User update(User user) {
        ...
    }

}
```

Then this is the test I'm running:

```
@RunWith(CdiRunner.class)
@AdditionalClasses(EntityManagerProvider.class)
public class DALUserTest {

    @Inject UserDAO userDAO;

    @Test
    public void testGetUser() {

        User user = userDAO.findByUsername("myUsername");

        assertNotNull(user);
    }
}
```

The test runs properly. The problem is that if I go to the MySQL console and run the command

```
show processlist;
```

I get the following output

[image]

As you can see, the test execution (after its termination of course) leaves a pending process in background in MySQL, which stays there until someone kills it. 
Moreover, anytime I run the test it adds more and more pending processes.

More info: I use `persistence.xml` to configure the connection. Hibernate is used as the implementation of JPA and [HikariCP](http://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/) as the connection pool provider.

What do you think about this problem? Could it be a HikariCP (or Hibernate) bug or a wrong usage of the EntityManager class?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be HikariCP, we fixed some issues with connection cleanup at shutdown in 1.3.9 (released this week).  You should upgrade if you have not already done so.

You *are* calling `HikariDataSource.close()` or `HikariDataSource.shutdown()`, right?  If you're running in a container, you can configure the container to call one of these methods in its *destroy* configuration.  If you do not shutdown the pool, it will indeed just abandon connections (any pool will).

If you were not calling `close()` or `shutdown()`, that would be the problem, but we of course always recommend running on the latest version of HikariCP.

Comment: Hi @brettw, thank you for the response. 
Two strange things happened: 

1) I've changed the HikariCP version from 1.3.8 to 1.3.9. Running the test throws this exception stack http://pastebin.com/6Uw8r9bK. It seems Hikari is having problems setting the minimum pool size 
2) I re-tried using the Hikari 1.3.8 version. Now the problem of the processes doesn't occour again! I don't know what to say; the problem went off withoud doing nothing..

Comment: ``minimumPoolSize`` was deprecated in 1.3.3 and removed in 1.3.9.  Use ``minimumIdle`` instead.  The issue in 1.3.8 was kind of timing sensitive, so you may not always see it.  I would recommend upgrading to 1.3.9 and changing ``minimumPoolSize`` to ``minimumIdle``.

Comment: I've done the changes you told (so now I'm using the 1.3.9 version and changed `minimumPoolSize` to `minimumIdle`).
Now I get a strange error when I run the test

http://pastebin.com/hY11zcL7

In the persistence.xml file I have 
   `<property name="hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle" value="20"/>
   <property name="hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize" value="100"/>`

Comment: Does the error persist if you switch the order of the two parameters?  I've pushed a version (1.4.0) that defers the bounds check until after all parameters have been set.  It will take about 3 hours from this comment before it appears in the maven central repository.

Comment: Yes, the error persists changing the order of the parameters in the persistence.xml file.

Comment: Ok.  1.4.0 should correct this issue.  In the meantime (the next 2-3 hours), just comment out ``minimumIdle``.

Comment: Thank you, the upgrade to the 1.4.0 version solved the issue :)